# Page builder not updating Page content

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I am using Page builder plugin (version 2.4.6). But i can not update my page content. If I change my page content it is set back to blank. I have updated plugin. I have deactivate all other plugin but same things happen.

**Why the page content not updated ?** Even I can not see the two button `(History and Live Editor button)` in editor.

**I am using wordpress plugin 4.3.1 version.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should roll back your page builder plugin to 2.2.2

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at their site, a lot of people are having this problem: https://siteorigin.com/thread/problem-with-page-builder-after-wordpress-and-theme-update/